# How to clear the cell value in C# using NPOI

Tags: c#, selenium, npoi

I have to clear the existing cell value using NPOI in C#

I tried this but not working 
 cell.SetCellValue(null);

Comment: Did you tried to remove cell?  `worksheet.GetRow(0).RemoveCell(0);`

Comment: Thanks @DanB, i tried with this and its working as expected  - 
 cell.SetCellValue(String.Empty);

Comment: Hi Saravanan, can you mark my answer as accepted?

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to remove cell?

```
worksheet.GetRow(0).RemoveCell(0);
```